# Prove for a triangle whose side are in AP

Tags: sequences-and-series, triangles, arithmetic-progressions

If the sides of a triangle are in AP and the greatest angle exceeds the smallest angle by a show that the sides are in the ratio 1 - X :1: 1 + X where X = √((1- cos a)(7-cos a))

Comment: There is a typo, $X$ should be $\sqrt {(1 - \cos a)/(7 - \cos a)}$.

Comment: Looks related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2865539/the-sides-of-a-triangle-are-in-arithmetic-progression